# TraMineR - Seqiplot include more x axis labels and rotation

Tags: r, dplyr, traminer

I would be very grateful for advice. I would would like to include all x-axis labels on ticks, reduce the font size so that they don't overlap and rotate them. In this example, there are 23 tick marks but only 12 1abels. I would like them all displayed. Many thanks!

```
data(mvad)
mvad=mvad%>%select(1:37)

mvad.labels <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
                 "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM","FE","HE","JL","SC","TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 15:37, states=mvad.scodes, labels=mvad.labels)
seqiplot(mvad.seq, withlegend=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below provides different options to obtain the desired goal. Note that I have chosen a tiny font size to illustrate the point. You can either use `TraMineR`'s `seqplot` command (which uses base R's `plot` environment) or `ggseqplot` (which uses `ggplot2` internally).

```r
library(TraMineR)
library(ggseqplot)
library(dplyr)


data(mvad)
mvad <- mvad |> select(1:37)

mvad.labels <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
                 "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM","FE","HE","JL","SC","TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 15:37, states=mvad.scodes, labels=mvad.labels)
#>  [>] state coding:
#>        [alphabet]  [label]  [long label]
#>      1  employment  EM       employment
#>      2  FE          FE       further education
#>      3  joblessness HE       higher education
#>      4  school      JL       joblessness
#>      5  training    SC       school
#>      6  NA          TR       training
#>  [>] 712 sequences in the data set
#>  [>] min/max sequence length: 23/23

# index plot with rotated labels and smaller font size
seqiplot(mvad.seq, 
         xtlab = attributes(mvad.seq)$names, # label every position
         cex.axis = .4, ylas = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# alternative approach using ggseqplot (wich uses ggplot internally)
# Option 1: labels in two lines
ggseqiplot(mvad.seq[1:10,],
           border = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = attributes(mvad.seq)$names,
                   guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2)) 
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

```r
# Option2: labels in one line but with smaller font size
ggseqiplot(mvad.seq[1:10,],
           border = T) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = attributes(mvad.seq)$names) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 5))
#> Scale for x is already present.
#> Adding another scale for x, which will replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: ggseqiplot worked perfectly - thank you so much!!